# How do i "delete" useless , after scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, eof

Here is a piece of my code :
And output looks like: 12, 44, 55, 
I need to remove the last one ", " and i tried everything.

```
while ((r = scanf("%d", &v)) > 0){
        printf("%d", v);
        printf(", ");
        }
```

Comment: Don't remove it. Write your program so it doesn't add the last one. There is a way... If you think about it. :)

Comment: There is a way... If you think about it ... or if you read dbush's reply ;)  Don't forget to "accept" if you find the answer helpful :)

Comment: Here are some numbers. Please copy them to paper as a comma separated list. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. How would you do that without ending up with a comma at the end? Imagine how you would do that if I speak this over a phone. What I want to illustrate (while there is already a good answer visible) is that pen and paper are a great programming tool for getting your own mind clear about a solution you are going to program. Often it even works to just do it on paper and watch yourself doing it and thereby come up with an algorithm almost magically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of printing the comma after each value, print it *before* each value except the first:

```
int first = 1;
while ((r = scanf("%d", &v)) > 0){
    if (!first) printf(", ");
    first = 0;
    printf("%d", v);
}
```